# Is there a way I can continuously change some text in certain interval of time?

Tags: flutter, dart

In some area, I want a list of objects to be continuously appeared replacing the previous one in a gap of 2 secs. And in that interval I wanna do some logic. 
I tried `Flutter.delayed` but it doesn't work accordingly in a while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `initState` method, use `Timer.periodic(...)`

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  // this code runs after every 2 seconds. 
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (timer) {
    if (_someCondition) {
      timer.cancel(); // if you want to stop this loop use cancel
    }

    setState(() {
      _string = "new value"; // your logic here
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a timer and put your logic in the function that handles the timer event.

...

...

```
initstate() {
   Timer.periodic( Duration(seconds: 2), (Timer t) {
      setState(() => displayTheNextElementOfTheList());
      ...
      //your logic here  
     });
    ...    
}
```